# How to return text values from Bootstrap Multi-Select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using bootstrap select for a multiple enabled dropdown.
When a button is pressed i'm building a variable to use in an AJAX request.

It works for returning the values (basically the ID's in this case), since it returns an array of values, i can use a loop to build the JSON.  However i also need to send the text value, but havent been able to get this working.

```
   $('#sendButton').click(function() {
    var modal = $('#modalPopup');
    var modalID = modal.data('value');
    var selectedOptionValue = $('#multiSelectBox').val();
    var selectedOptionName = $('#multiSelectBox').text();
    var sendRequest = {
        'modalNo': modalID,
        'products': []
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptionValue.length; i++) {
        sendRequest.products.push({
            'productId': selectedOptionValue[i],
            'productName': selectedOptionName
        });
    }
   });
```

I tried another loop to do `selectedOptionName[j]` when building the request but no luck, i end up getting all of the text values in my drop down.  Tried using:

```
var selectedOptionName = $('#multiSelectBox:selected').text();
```

But this doesn't return anything.  Any ideas?

HTML for drop down:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple id="multiSelectBox" title="Select Product(s)"></select>
```

Code to populate dropdown:

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++){
        html += '<option value ="' + data.products[i].productId+ '">' + data.products[i].productName+ '</option>'
    }
    $('#multiSelectBox').html(html);    
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: Can you provide related HTML code?

Comment: Added HTML/Code to populate drop down

Comment: Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrbd8xg/) what you want?

Comment: Thanks, thats not quite it though, im using a multi select text box, so it's getting all the selected option text, in a way that i can pair them up with their ID's.  If it returned them all in an array with the values that'd be great.

Comment: Ok, I didn't read question attentively, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is

> $("#multiSelectBox option:selected").text()

but this will give you a string of all selected text. So you need to find the text by value in your loop.I didn't check for syntax here, there might be typos.

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptionValue.length; i++) {

var val = selectedOptionValue[i]; 
var txt = $("#multiSelectBox option[value='"+val+"']").text();

        sendRequest.products.push({
            'productId': val ,
            'productName': txt 
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thats great mate, sorted, i was trying to do it all with the first option:selected bit, rather than going and finding the relevant text.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT ALL WITH FILTER**

```
<h1 class="monthofyear">monthofyear: <span></span></h1>



  $(document).ready(function() { $('#monthofyear').multiselect({ includeSelectAllOption: true,
  onSelectAll: function(element, checked) {
    var selected = [];
    $('#monthofyear option:selected').each(function(index, brand) {
      selected.push([$(this).val()]);
    });
    $("h1.monthofyear span").text(selected);
  },
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  enableFiltering: true,
  maxHeight: '300',
  buttonWidth: '235',
  onChange: function(element, checked) {
    var brands = $('#monthofyear option:selected');
    var selected = [];
    $(brands).each(function(index, brand) {
      selected.push([$(this).val()]);
    });
    $("h1.monthofyear span").text(selected);

  }
});});
```